How can Devi be described as Vidya and Avidya both?
I've been reading "Devi for Millenials" by Bibek Debroy, and it has a Section on Devi Gita from the Devi Bhagvat Purana - https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_giitaa/deviigiitaa.html
My query pertains to the following verse from the Chapter 1:

विमर्श इति तां प्राहुः शैवशास्त्रविशारदाः ।
अविद्यामितरे प्राहुर्वेदतत्त्वार्थचिन्तकाः ॥ १०॥


vimarsha iti taam' praahuh' shaivashaastravishaaradaah' .
avidyaamitare praahurvedatattvaarthachintakaah' .. 10..


Those who are accomplished in texts about Shiva call her Vimarsha. Others, who have thought about the meanings of the Vedas, speak of her as Avidya.

What does the above mean? Why should anyone consider Devi as Avidya?

It is a brilliant question.
The Maya that keeps us attached to this material world is the Devi. So she is Avidya.

Human beings are full of longings towards their children, O hero; do they not pass from greed for self unto mutual benefaction; dost thou not perceive this? Nevertheless they are hurled into the whirlpool of selfishness which is the pit of delusion; through the power of the Great Illusion they make worldly existence permanent. Marvel not then at this. This is the contemplation-sleep of the lord of the world, and the Great Illusion that comes from Hari; by it the world is completely deluded. Verily she, the adorable goddess, Great Illusion, forcibly drawing the minds even of those who know, presents them to delusion. By her is created this whole universal both moveable and immoveable; she it is who when propitious bestows boons on men with a view to their final emancipation, She is Knowledge supreme; she is the eternal cause of final emancipation, and the cause of the bondage of worldly existence; she indeed is the queen over all lords. - Devi Mahatmya or Sri Sri Chandi 1.38-46

As you can see she is both Avidya as she deludes all the creatures, but at the same time she is who grants liberation; so she is also Vidya.
You might find this perplexing. But, imagine who binds you, only he can liberate you from that bondage. To understand it completely, you need to understand the Samkhya philosophy. In short, according to Samkhya, there are two things-Prakriti (the cause of the material world) and Purusa (pure consciousness). These are distinct. By delusion, we think, we are part of this material world. The knowledge that Prakriti and Purusa are different leads to liberation. What is Prakriti in Samkhya Darshana, that very thing is known as Devi.

And thou art the original source (prakṛti) of the universe, the exciting cause of the three qualities - Devi Mahatmya or Sri Sri Chandi 1.59

The Buddhi or Intelligence is the product of the Prakriti.

From Prakriti evolved Mahat (or Buddhi or Intelligence); thence Ahamkara; and from this, the sixteen fold set; from five, again, among the sixteen fold, the five Elements. -Samkhya Karika 22

Using this intelligence one can do a variety of things good or bad. According to Samkhya Buddhi has eight Vrittis. Out of which 7 Vrittis make a person bound to this universe. The 8th Vritti brings Apavarga or liberation. When Buddhi becomes full of sattva guna, it pushes a person towards liberation. So the same intelligence can bring bondage and can lead to liberation. Depends on how it operates.

Ascertainment is Buddhi. Virtue, knowledge, dispassion and power are its forms or manifestations or modifications, partaking of Sattva. Those partaking of Tamas, are the reverse of these. - Samkhya Karika 23


(The other Indriyas present all objects to Buddhi, so that they may be exhibited to Purusa), since it is Buddhi which accomplishes the experience of Purusa in regard to all (objects at all times). And it is that, again, which discriminates the subtile difference between the Pradhana (Prakriti) and Purusa. -Samkhya Karika 37

So, by using Buddhi when we realize the distinction between Prakriti and Purusha that knowledge leads to liberation. Thus, you see the same Buddhi can bind you and liberate you, and so does the great Goddess (Devi).

Nice answer, but I want to add that there is a different viewpoint also. In this viewpoint, Devi is not just maya, but She is a feminine manifestation of brahman. So She would be exactly equal to Vishnu or Shiva and not just their Shakti.

@estimator Yes, that's true. In fact, Devi Bhagavata says that Devi is the supreme being and Siva, Vishnu and Brahma are subordinate to her. There are many Brahmandas and each has one Siva, Vishnu and Brahma. The supreme Devi resides in the Manidvipa and she (Devi Bhagavati) gave her Shaktis (Sarasvati, Lakshmi and kali) to these Devas so that they can perform the task of creation, maintenance and dissolution.

Your question What does the above mean? Why should anyone consider Devi as Avidya?
Not every one but it is Vedāntins alone whereas Shaiva followers treat Her as vimarśa [intelligence]. Let us reproduce the 10th sloka of Devi Gita:
विमर्श इति तां प्राहुः शैवशास्त्रविशारदाः |
अविद्यामितरे प्राहुर्वेदतत्त्वार्थचिन्तकाः || १० ||
vimarśa iti tāṃ prāhuḥ śaiva-śāstra-viśāradāḥ |
avidyāmitare prāhur-veda-tattvārtha-cintakāḥ || 10 ||

The Shaiva authors call Her Vimarśa [विमर्श/Intelligence] and the other Vedāntins 
call Her Avidyā [अविद्या/Ignorance].|| 10 ||

Notes: in short this Māyā is in the heads of all the Pandits. 
This Māyā is called various in the Nigamas [निगम].

From the above above sloka-10, Māyā has been interpreted pandits differently according to the philosophy they follow. The Saiva pandits take Māyā to Vimarśa [विमर्श] or Buddhi (aka Mahat an evolute from Māyā/Prakriti); this is Intelligence principle. However, Vedanta followers interpret Māyā as Avidyā (अविद्या) which means ignorance of our real self (Jiva) Who is non-different from Brahman. Each case of Shaiva and Vedanta interpretation of Māyā has been discussed separately below.
I) According to Saiva Siddhanta scriptures, Ānava, Karma and Māyā are said to be the malas of the jīva. Of these, ānava (ignorance) is the cause of samsāra (cycle of birth and death) of the soul by fostering ignorance. But māyā helps the soul to get freed from ignorance and thus be liberated from births. That which propels the jīva through the inducement of darkness, having māyā for its (jiva's) prop, is karma.
Maya, according to the karmas of the souls, becomes the body, etc. of the souls. Till the souls obtain jnāna to attain the Grace of God, māyā helps the souls like a lamp (buddhi/intelligence) which gives light to people till the dawn of the sun (jnāna).
So, the Shaiva authors call Her Vimarśa [विमर्श/intelligence].

II)  According to Advaida scriptures, Avidya (अविद्या) is Ignorance like Ānava of Saiva Siddhanta. However, what is form of Avidya? This is described in Tattava Bhodha (a Prakarana Grantha by Adi Sankarāchārya) as given below:
कारणशरीरं किम्?
अनिर्वाच्यानाद्यविद्यारूपं शरीरद्वयस्य कारणमात्रं ।
सत्स्वरूपाऽज्ञानं निर्विकल्पकरूपं यदस्ति तत्कारणशरीरम् ॥ ३.३ ॥

What is the Causal body [Kārana sarīra/कारणशरीरं]? 
That which is inexplicable, beginningless and in the form of Avidya [ignorance of
the Reality], the cause for the other two bodies [the subtle and the gross], 
ignorant of one’s own real nature [Self], free from duality or division,
is the Kārana sarīra [कारणशरीरं/Causal body]. ॥ 3.3 ॥

Kārana sarīra is the form of Avidya who causes the other two bodies which are Subtle body (Sūkshma Sarīra/सूक्ष्म शरीर) and Gross body (Sthūla Sarīra/स्थूल शरीर).
How does Sūkshma Sarīra cause jīvatman to appear? This is explained in sloka [9.1]:
स्थूलशरीराभिमानि जीवनामकं ब्रह्मप्रतिबिम्बं भवति ।
स एव जीवः प्रकृत्या स्वस्मात् ईश्वरं भिन्नत्वेन जानाति ॥ ९.१ ॥ 

The reflection [as it were] of Brahman [in Sūkshma Sarīra] which identifies itself
with the gross body is called jīvatman. This jīvatman by nature [ignorance] takes 
Iswara to be different from himself.॥ 9.1 ॥ 

As upādhi, how does Maya project Isvara and jīvatman? This is nicely described in sloka [9.2 & 9.3].
अविद्योपाधिः सन् आत्मा जीव इत्युच्यते ॥ ९.२॥
The consciousness [Atman] conditioned (Upādhi) by Avidya is called Jīvatman.॥ 9.2॥
Beware-1: Avidya is also known as Asuddha Māyā.

मायोपाधिः सन् ईश्वर इत्युच्यते ॥ ९.३॥
The awareness conditioned by Maya is called Isvara.॥ 9.3॥
Beware-2: Maya acting as upādhi for Isvara is known as Suddha Māyā.

So long as the notion which is due to difference in the conditionings (upādhi) that Jīvatman and Isvara are different, remains, until such time, there is no redemption from Samsāra (cycle of birth and death). The Jiva is endowed with ego and his knowledge is limited. (Where as) Isvara, is without ego and is omniscient.
Thus, jīvatman is ignorant his own real nature (caused by Avidya) and identifies with these Sthūla and Sūkshma sarīras undergoing samsāra (cycle of existence/cycle of birth and death). When jīvatman becomes the knower of the Self, through Sādhana Chatushtaya (fourfold qualifications) which is the means of liberation, having crossed the Samsāra, attains the Supreme Bliss here itself. [sloka:1]
So, the Vedāntins call Her Avidyā [अविद्या/Ignorance].

